# Cannot change the hint text style in flutter. What is the reason?

Tags: css, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have auto-calculated value boxes in flutter. Here is the **code for that**:

```
enum UnitType {
  meter,
  centimeter,
  feet,
}

class Units extends StatelessWidget {
  Units({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final TextEditingController _feetController =
      TextEditingController(text: '0');
  final TextEditingController _centimeterController =
      TextEditingController(text: '0');
  final TextEditingController _meterController =
      TextEditingController(text: '0');

  void _convertUnit(UnitType type) {
    double? ft = double.tryParse(_feetController.value.text) ?? 0;
    double? cm = double.tryParse(_centimeterController.value.text) ?? 0;
    double? m = double.tryParse(_meterController.value.text) ?? 0;

    switch (type) {
      case UnitType.feet:
        _meterController.text = (ft / 3.281).toString();
        _centimeterController.text = (ft * 30.48).toString();
        break;
      case UnitType.meter:
        _centimeterController.text = (m * 100).toString();
        _feetController.text = (m * 3.281).toString();
        break;
      case UnitType.centimeter:
        _meterController.text = (cm / 100).toString();
        _feetController.text = (cm / 30.48).toString();
        break;
    }
  }
```

A picture of what I am doing:  [image]

Now the Problem is that I cannot change the Hint Text color, alignment, or any other decorations.
`Code` of the `textformfield`:

```
Neumorphic(
            style: NeumorphicStyle(
              color: HexColor("E19D4D"),
              depth: -3,
            ),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _feetController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                onChanged: (_) => _convertUnit(UnitType.feet),
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

`Current Output`: [image]
Here the **input text color is black and aligned left**. I want the text to be **white and aligned center.**

Comment: `textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,),`

Comment: `TextFormField(
textAlign: TextAlign.center,
style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,),
                controller: _feetController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                onChanged: (_) => _convertUnit(UnitType.feet),
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
                ),
              ),
            ),`

Comment: Replace your TextFormField with this TextFormField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code I changed a few things this is how you want it.

```
  Neumorphic(
              style: NeumorphicStyle(
                color: Colors.amber,
                depth: -3,
              ),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                child: TextFormField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
                  controller: _feetController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

OutPut :[image]